# UISplitViewController with custom master view controller that is not UITableViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I'm working on an iPad application that requires a UISplitViewController. For the Master view controller I would like to use a custom view controller that has an image, a table view , and a label. Out of the box the UISplitviewcontroller/MasterDetail template give me a Navigation controller with an embedded UItableViewcontroller. When I attempt to change out the tableview controller for a new Viewcontroller the view for the new controller is not being presented. I am able to set the UIBarbuttons but none of the datasource methods for the table view are being called. Also the imageview and the label are not being presented. I've made sure that my view controller is the delegate and datasource for the tableview and set the preferred size in the awake from nib still no UI. I'm adding the UISprlitviewcontroller to an existing project could this be an issue?

Comment: Did you explicitly conform to UITableViewDatasource and UITableViewDelegate in the .h or .m of the view controller subclass?

Comment: I did. I think the issue I was having was in the use of size classes not knowing how to set them up properly. Since the app is iPad only I turned off the size classes and the Splitviewcontroller is working as expected. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the use of size classes. Since this is an iPad app only I turned off the size classes option and the app is working as expected. I need to invest time in learning how to properly use this new feature.